# Does Validation.IsValid() cache its results?

Tags: validation, asp.net-webpages

In a typical ASP.NET Web Pages page containing validation, there will be something like:

```
if (IsPost && Validation.IsValid()) {
    // Process valid data here
}
```

Inside my HTML, I need to add various classes to certain elements for presentation purposes. Is it safe to call Validation.IsValid() there or will it trigger validation over and over again?

Edit: to make it clear, I'm asking about additional calls to IsValid, like this somewhere down the cshtml file:

```
<input type="text" class="forminput @(Validation.IsValid() ? "" : "error")" />
```

Comment: As you add IsPost condition it'll be triggered for every post back

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear. It's about the subsequent calls to IsValid() on the same page.

Comment: So you are worried whether or not the _code_ behind the validation might be run again completely when you call this method? Well then just put the result of one single call into a variable, and use that variable afterwards in your conditions …

Comment: Yes that would be a solution. The question is whether there is a problem in the first place - does IsValid() execute validation over and over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `Validation.IsValid()` without any arguments causes *every* form field to be examined for validation errors every time the method is called. If an entry has been added to the `ModelState` dictionary on a previous call, it will still be there in subsequent calls - assuming that there hasn't been a `Postback` in between calls, which will of course clear all state.

You can limit the number of fields that are checked by passing their names into the method:

```
if(Validation.IsValid("Email")){
    // will only examine the form field named "Email"
}
```

Comment: So I need to define some custom variable and decide based on it? I probably do, as I haven't found a property like `Validation.WasValidLastTime`.

Comment: If you want to press on regardless of previous results of calls to `Validation.IsValid`, then yes, I guess you would have to use an alternative approach. If `IsValid` returned `false` previously, it will continue to do so. But I think you are over-complicating things. Take a look at my article on how the Validation systems works in Web Pages, especially how `Validation.ClassFor` works: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/191/Validation-In-Razor-Web-Pages-2